# How to test if a TImage has a graphic assigned to it?

Tags: delphi, testing, components, variable-assignment, timage

There's a TImage component on a form in my program.

In some situation, the program must test:

If "there is an image assigned to the picture property of the TImage component" then ...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
if Image1.Picture.Graphic = NIL 
then ShowMessage("There is no image.")
else ShowMessage("Image found.");
```

If working with bitmaps, you can also do this:

```
if Image.Picture.Bitmap.Empty then ShowMessage("There is no spoon");
```

Comment: `if NOT Image.Picture.Empty then DoStuff` as the OP asked to run `DoStuff`only when there's a picture.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo - I just supposed that the OP knows how to adjust the code (use a negation) to adapt it for its needs :)

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never!
The right way is:

`if Assigned(Image1.Picture.Graphic) then ...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but I'll assume you're talking about Delphi.

You can check whether there's a bitmap in the TImage control by testing:

```
if Image.Picture.Bitmap.Width > 0 then
  // do whatever
```

Comment: I think that testing for the presence of the object itself is better than testing for one of the properties of that object.